# Substitute Dense_Rank() value with Newid() value in TSQL?

Tags: t-sql

is it possible to substitute the value generated by Dense_Rank() with a Newid() value in TSQL? I use Dense_Rank() for grouping but I need a uniqueidentifier generated instead of an integer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get your `dense_rank()` calculated, select on that DISTINCT value, generate a `newid()` for each distinct `dense_rank()` and then join it back to the original `dense_rank()` determination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct way to do this, but as I mentioned in my comment, you can get your `dense_rank()` for each record, then generate a `NEWID()` for each distinct `Dense_Rank()`, then join it back to itself.

```
CREATE TABLE test(f1 int, f2 char(1));
INSERT INTO test 
VALUES (1, 'a'),
  (1, 'b'),
  (1, 'c'),
  (2, 'a'),
  (2, 'b'),
  (3, 'a'),
  (3, 'd'),
  (3, 'g');

With dr AS (SELECT f1, f2, dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY f1 ORDER BY f2) as dr FROM test)
,dr_newid AS (SELECT dr, newid() as nid FROM (SELECT dr FROM dr GROUP BY dr) as drsub)
SELECT dr.f1, dr.f2, dr.dr, dr_newid.nid
FROM dr LEFT OUTER JOIN dr_newid ON dr.dr = dr_newid.dr
ORDER BY f1, f2;

+----+----+----+--------------------------------------+
| f1 | f2 | dr |                 nid                  |
+----+----+----+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | a  |  1 | 966389AF-4C70-4AA8-A5C9-6F9537B8A1B8 |
|  1 | b  |  2 | 73BE2978-B7D7-46B8-8B04-3103C8410575 |
|  1 | c  |  3 | CB935CCA-AFE5-4D13-9583-0440DF1BEFE2 |
|  2 | a  |  1 | 966389AF-4C70-4AA8-A5C9-6F9537B8A1B8 |
|  2 | b  |  2 | 73BE2978-B7D7-46B8-8B04-3103C8410575 |
|  3 | a  |  1 | 966389AF-4C70-4AA8-A5C9-6F9537B8A1B8 |
|  3 | d  |  2 | 73BE2978-B7D7-46B8-8B04-3103C8410575 |
|  3 | g  |  3 | CB935CCA-AFE5-4D13-9583-0440DF1BEFE2 |
+----+----+----+--------------------------------------+
```

One caveat here though... depending on how your box performs the join from `dr` to `dr_newid` it may generate unique newids for each distinct dense_rank value. Using a LEFT JOIN should trick the optimizer into generating the `dr_newid` intermediate result set once to be joined back. An `INNER JOIN` though may not.

If it's giving incorrect results, you may dump that dr_newid out to a temp table and then join back, forcing the server to derive the newid() once for each distinct `dense_rank()` and avoid tricks to force the optimizer's logic.

[sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/89205/10)